# Use Matplotlib color graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a histogram using SNS, with the following code.

results represents a binary variable.

```
sns.histplot(probabilities, hue= results)
```

probabilities has the same length - are both 1D

But I get the error

```
ValueError: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data: `hue`
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: It has the same length!

Comment: probability is 1D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like seaborn.histplot prefers a dataframe style:

```
sns.histplot(data=pd.DataFrame({'prob':probabilities,
                                'true':np.where(y_test == 1, 'red', 'blue')
                                }),
             x='prob', hue='true')
```

Comment: Note that you'd need `palette={0:'red', 1:'blue'}` to assign specific colors.  Also, `multiple='stack'` as the default plots the bars upon each other.